# How to go to boot options?

Tags: startup

I have a MacBookPro Retina 13" early 2015 and I can not enter the boot options.
The Device is running OS X El Capitan.

I have tried the following things with no luck:

#### Attempt 1 - Hold the Option

1. Restart
2. press and hold left <kbd>option</kbd> right after hearing the chime

Result: Black Screen, I need to press and hold the power key to make the device boot.

I have also tried this with an external keyboard with the same result.

#### Attempt 2 - SMC Reset

1. Restart
2. Reset the System Management Controller by pressing and holding <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> right after the chime, until the next chime.
3. Retry Attempt 1

Result: Same as Attempt 1.

Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> should be held right after pressing the power button including during the boot chime until Startup Manager is shown (https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202796). Holding the key only once the chime has happened may be too late.

Comment: Let's say I pressed it too late, wouldn't you then expect a normal boot from the drive instead of a black screen? Anyway, I tried it nonetheless, no luck.